# What is the difference of x=x+3 and x+=3? Why one needs type cast and the other does not?

Tags: java, casting, compound-operator

Question :

```
char x = 'a'; 
x += 3; // ok  
x = x + 3; // compile time error
```

Comment: try `x *= 1.1` which also compiles, x becomes `j` ;)

Answer (score 29):

Because `x += 3` is equivalent to `x = (char)(x+3)`,  while `x + 3` is default to `int` operation, assign an int to char must cast.

From the [`JLS specification : 15.26.2`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#5304) ,

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once. Note that the implied cast to type T may be
>   either an identity conversion (?.1.1) or a narrowing primitive
>   conversion (?.1.3).